# Vue3, ElementPlus: Icon is not rendering within el-tab-pane while render the el-tabs using 'h' instance in Vue3 composition API

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

**Environment**

- Vue Version: 3.3.2
- Element Plus Version: 2.3.4
- Browser / OS: Chrome
- Build Tool: Vite

**Related Component**

- el-tab-pane

**Steps to reproduce**

- Please click the below links for minimal reproduction section
- Reproduction Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-oo52wq?file=package.json,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue

**Scenario:**

- I'm try to render the dynamic tabs using Vue3 composition api and 'h' instance with array of object data value. For me, el-tabs and el-tab-pane with label are rendered successfully.
- I additionally set slot label, and element plus icon class name for el-tab-pane component.
- Data schema is available in the above shared link and the page name is Helloworld.vue page.

**Actual Issue:**

- Icon not getting render within el-tab-pane.
- slot label is not working for me.

**What is actually happening?**

- Icon is not render within el-tab-pane header.
- Label value only render within el-tab-pane header

**Additional comments**
**Note:**

- The above reported issue (icon, slot label for el-tab-pane) is working fine in Vue2 options API and element-ui.
- We're facing the above issue while migrate from vue2 to vue3 composition api and element-ui to element plus
- Need to render icon within el-tab-pane component.

Comment: Looking at your stackblitz, my recommendation is to not try to invent a new template syntax, it's a portal to software hell. Stick to HTML or JSX.